# How can I pass a variable to a partial which is shared with another controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a User model and a Profile model.
A User `has_one` Profile and a Profile `belongs_to` User.

From within `app/views/users/show.html.erb`, I would like to display the user's associated profile details.

I created a partial at `app/views/profiles/shared/_show.html.erb`. It contains:

```
<p>
  <strong>Title:</strong>
  <%= @profile.title %>
</p>
```

I am trying to include this partial from within `app/views/users/show.html.erb` like so (as recommended in the [API documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/PartialRenderer.html#class-ActionView::PartialRenderer-label-Rendering+shared+partials)):

```
<%= render partial: 'profiles/shared/show', locals: { profile: @user.profile }%>
```

However, I keep getting the error:

```
undefined method `title' for nil:NilClass
```

If I remove the `<%= @profile.title %>` line from the partial, it renders correctly (so I assume the path is correct).

I have also checked that `@user.profile` contains a valid `Profile` object. It does.

What am I missing? How can I pass a variable to a partial which is shared with another controller?

Comment: try just `profile.title`

Comment: Aw man, you rock! That was it. If you add that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`locals` option in the `render` method, make a new variable with value from the hash `locals: { foo: @bar }`, instead of shared `@` instance variable.

Answer (score 3):

just remove the `@` from `@profile.title` as it is not a instance variable but a local variable so you don't need `@`

**Note: do have a check in that partial for safety.**

Comment: "Note: do have a check in that partial for safety." — Could you expand on that? What should I check?

Comment: you said its shared between controllers. so you'll have to be sure a profile is passed everytime to the partial. else the code'll break.

Comment: Sorry man, promised it to Зелёный before you replied (see comments).

Comment: @JackZelig No problem dude.. The important thing is that you got your answer. :)